# Sharepoint 2013 Client Object Model - How to set 'View all files'

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have written in C# using the Client Object Model libraries (Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client) to create a hierarchy of lists containing a number of files, at various levels.  In order to view all the files, I can Edit the View, and in the Folders section, change to *Show all items without Folders*.

Question is, is there way to do this programmatically? Currently the code creates a large number of sites, and to change the view manually for each would be a real pain.

Comment: I'm not clear exactly what your code is doing. It sounds like it's showing files in a specific view of a library, but then you mention that it also creates a large number of sites? Perhaps it would help if you showed us the code you're currently using.

Comment: Hi Thriggle, the code itself isn't showing the files in the library, but it just needs to be able to change the view

Comment: Ah, I think I see... so you want code that will change an existing view so that it shows all items without folders?

Comment: @Thriggle
Sorry, struggling with the comment box here ... :-(
The code itself isn't showing the files in the library, it just needs to be able to change the view so that the files in the list have a flat structure.

So I programmatically create a number of subsites, and these contain a list which has a deep nested structure containing directories and files.
In sharepoint, I see the directory structure rather than just the list of files.
 I can change this in the Settings for the view, but I have to do that for each subsite, and I want to be able to do this programmatically.

Comment: Yes - exactly! Sorry, new to Sharepoint, so not expressing myself well!

Comment: This is the snippet of the code that creates the subsite:
 
    `SPC.WebCollection subSites = web.Webs;
    SPC.WebCreationInformation webCreationInfo = new SPC.WebCreationInformation();
    webCreationInfo.Url = rpID;
    ....
 subSites.Add(webCreationInfo);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to update the [`Scope`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.view.scope.aspx) property of your [`View`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.view.aspx) object to be [`Recursive` (`1`) or `RecursiveAll` (`2`)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.viewscope.aspx).

- **Recursive** will give you **all files** (regardless of which folders they're in).
- **RecursiveAll** will give you **all files and folders** (regardless of which folders they're in).

For example:

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
Web site = clientContext.Web;
List targetList = site.Lists.GetByTitle("My List");
View targetView = targetList.Views.GetByTitle("My View");
targetView.Scope = ViewScope.RecursiveAll;
targetView.Update();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Hi Thriggle, 

Thank you, that (almost) did the trick. One minor point, in your code, where you initialise targetView, should that be:

`View targetView = targetList.Views.GetByTitle("My View");`

The only other thing that I had to do was change the enumeration to 'FilesOnly' rather than 'RecursiveAll'

Many, many thanks!

Comment: Ah, good catch! I'll update the code in my answer when I get the chance.

Comment: Thanks - one more minor point, I did some further testing and the enumeration I needed was not the 'FilesOnly' but the 'Recursive', as 'FilesOnly' only gave me the files at the level.

Comment: @Thriggle.. Nice...+1